# My HTC EVO 3D is unresponsive after charging

Tags: charging, system-freeze, htc-evo-3d

For about the past month or so, whenever I pull my HTC Evo 3d off the charger (wall primarily, haven't tested against USB yet) the phone is unresponsive for anywhere between 15-60 seconds, and it's getting worse.

If I pull the phone off with the display turned on, it will stay turned on in a frozen state; it does the same if I pull it off with the display off, just frozen with the display turned off. The battery is frequently incredibly warm but not quite hot. The unit is running stock Android (after a couple of updates; 2.3.4 Gingerbread, Sense 3.0).

- What could be causing this? To me it sounds like some kind of power regulation problem, perhaps from it switching from AC to battery power.
- How can I diagnose what is going on that is causing the overheat (is overheating a regularly reported defect of the Evo 3D)?
- I am becoming more worried about long-term damage not only from the freezing, but from just charging my phone. So, most importantly, what steps should I take to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have minimized the impact of this problem by disabling the `[Stay Awake]` setting (Settings | Applications | Development).

This setting had been enabled and once I had turned it back off the screen display became responsive sooner after unplugging. Apparently this setting on the HTC-Evo 3D is problematic.

Comment: If there are any workarounds for this setting being problematic I would be happy to hear it as my phone frequently remains plugged in while I work, and I regularly use it.